# Horizontal scroll to follow vertical scroll position and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I can make it work one way. But then horizontal scroll doesnt work at all.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  $(document).scrollLeft($(document).scrollTop());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2zu91k4s/3/

How can I make it work both ways? Horizontal scroll to follow vertical and when I scrolled horizontally, vertical scroll to follow ScrollLeft position?

Also it seems like Chrome new smooth scroll feature make it impossible to scroll with mouse wheel (it works fine in Opera 35 with stepped scroll). Any thoughts how to work with it?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to differentiate between horizontal and vertical scrolling.  Something like this would work:

```
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
        //horizontal scroll
        lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
        $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollLeft());
    } else {
            //vertical scroll
        $(document).scrollLeft($(document).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/2zu91k4s/4/

Hope that helps!